# why is this O(nlogn)

Tags: arrays, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

I had a internship interview today and I couldn't figure this out.

```
total = 0

product(int array[]) {

    if (array.length == 1) {
        return array[0]
    } else {
        product(product right side array  * product left side )
    }
}
```

Comment: So what du u think it should be?

Comment: Think about why are algorithms logarithmic? Hint: run this code on a piece of paper and see what happens. Then change the size of the input and see how much more/less time you would need to run the code on paper.  (Look at the way problems are divided into small problems)

Comment: How are "product right side array" and "product left side" implemented? Does that make a deep copy of the array?

Comment: @albert Did you meant: `product(left side) * product(right side)` ?. I deleted my answer, it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is O(N log N) because the number of times each value is copied is O(log N).

Imagine you have multiple levels. At the first level there is N items in one array, at the second level N/2 items in 2 arrays, at the third level N/4 items in 4 arrays etc until you have 1 item in N arrays.  This takes log2(n) levels to go from top to bottom.  Each value has been copied log2(N) times meaning the time complexity is O(log(N) * N), as the base of the log doesn't matter.

You might say that other operations like `*` and `new Array` are more expensive, however these are O(N) and as N grows only the higher orders matter.

Answer (score 0):

`product(left side) * product(right side)` is going to return a single number, so the outer call to `product` is going to take O(1).

The two inner calls are simply doing a binary tree depth-first walk through the array, and that takes O(n) time.

However, at each level of the walk it is doing the outer call to `product`, and there are O(logn) levels, and at each level the cost is O(1), so that multiplies the effort by O(logn), so you get O(nlogn).

Comment: There is N values, so only (N-1) multiplications no matter how you divide the work.

Comment: @Peter: You're right about the number of multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when the array is of length 1 the time is constant, and if it is of length n, then 2 recursive calls  with the half of the array are used.

A little bit more formally, using induction on the length n of the array.  In the base case, the small size of array is 1, and obviously the number of operations is a constant (this matches O(nlog n)...and everything).

In the general inductive case, with an array length of n, both recursive calls `product right side array` and `product left side` involve n/2 elements (you divide the array in 2 parts), and therefore the number of operations is

n/2 (log n/2) + n/2 (log_2 n/2) = n/2 (log n -1) + n/2 (log n -1) = n log n -2.

In this case the if operation counts as 1 additional operation and the product * itself as one more, which gives a total of n log n, but adding a constant is not relevant.

You can also think that the recursive calls `product(product right side array  * product left side )`  has a  "depth" of log n (in the case of starting with 256, the "depth" of the recursive calls would be 8), because each time the size of the array is the half of the initial one. Since finally the n elements are returned this gives O(n log(n))

Answer (score 0):

The height of the recursion tree is at most *log_2 n*, because that is the number of times you can halve *n* before reaching *n = 1* (i.e., a leaf node) -- think of *log_2 n* as the number of bits in *n*.

The width of *each level* of the tree is at most *n* (at the bottom, each array element is visited exactly once; the upper levels of the tree are obviously narrower).

At each branch, a constant time (*O(1)*) multiplication operation is performed (assuming, for this argument, that array splitting is constant time).

Therefore an upper bound on the number of operations is *O(1) x n x log_2 n = O(n log n)*.